# How can I protect a wall from flames of a gas hob?

Tags: kitchens

The flames of our gas hob scorches the wall behind it and the chipboard panel next to it. Is there any material I can affix to those sides to stop this potential fire hazard from happening?

Comment: You should probably move the hob. If it's close enough to scorch things, it's too close to them.

Comment: It's built into the surface and therefore impractical

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of tile would do the job. If ceramic is too thick, or hard to install, adhesive stainless steel squares should be nicely heat conductive, thin, and easy to put up.

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=Stainless+Peel+Stick+Tile.

Comment: If it's heat conductive, won't it just heat up the wall behind it?

Comment: It'll spread the heat out. A single sheet would be best, but even w smaller tiles you should get enough of a spread to reduce scorching temps at any one point.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds worthwhile trying out. The wall is too flimsy to hold ceramic tiles

Answer (score 0):

The range in our kitchen is pushed up against a wall (the chimney is behind it) so the back burner is in a corner.  When I installed a ceramic tile backsplash I wrapped it around to completely cover this corner since I was noticing some discoloration of the paint from the gas burner.  So far this seems to be working fine.